# Syntax errors in template method that I don't understand

Tags: c++, templates, vector, syntax, compiler-errors

I wrote a short template method for a school project, and am getting weird syntax errors that I don't understand. They have something to do with the template I declared (when commenting out the header containing the template, all errors in main() go away) but I can't figure out what is going on. I'm including  and "intersectHeader.h" and using the std namespace.
In my main() function, all I'm doing is declaring a vector:

> vector v1; -- errors: C2065 'string' undeclared identifier,
>   C2065 'v1' undeclared identifier, C2065 'vector' undeclared identifier

This is the template:

```
template<typename T>   
vector<T> intersect(const vector<T> & v1, const vector<T> & v2)    
{    
    vector<T> resultVector;

    bool duplicate = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        duplicate = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < v2.size(); j++)
        {
            if (v1[i] == v2[j])
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < resultVector.size(); a++)
                {
                    if (v1[i] == resultVector[a])
                    {
                        duplicate = true;
                        break;
                    } 
                } 

                if (!duplicate)
                {
                    resultVector.push_back(v1[i]);
                } 
            } 
        }
    } 

    return resultVector;
}
```

The above gives me these errors:

> C2988 unrecognizable template declaration/definition, C2143 syntax
>   error missing ';' before '<', C2059 syntax error '<'.

All of which occur in the second line "vector intersect(const vector & v1,
const vector & v2)"

Comment: I don't know why the <> aren't showing up in the code, but the declaration is: template<typename T>
vector<T> intersect(const vector<T> & v1, const vector<T> & v2) and the variable vector<T> resultVector;

Comment: Please copy-paste the complete error output into the body of the question, use code-formatting so all characters will be shown. Also please point out (with e.g. comments) where in the code the errors are. And if possible please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: At least show all the includes and "using namespace" things you have. Or better, remove all the using directives and prefix the relevant names with the appropriate qualifier.

Comment: Not much to go on here, but have you done `#include <vector>` before your template method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do `using namespace std` in any header files.  You should add the explicitly `std::` namespace to your template implementation, and the problem should go away (assuming you have included the appropriate standard library headers).

Comment: @Rick: You're welcome.  Please consider "accepting" this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.   Welcome to SO.